# Python subprocess module: How to reopen PIPE?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a piece of code that needs to run node js. In order to write to the file for node js to recieve the command, I use the following code:

```py
def execute(comm):
    file_number = proc.stdin.fileno()
    file = open(file_number, "w+")
    file.write(comm)
    file.close()

execute("""console.log("hi");""")
execute("""console.log("bye");""")
```

However, when I run execute a second time, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?
Here is the full code:

```py
import subprocess
import threading
import time

class nodePrompt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen("node", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        self.on_out_func = print
        self.on_out_args=[]
        self.on_out_kwargs={}
        self.on_err_func = print
        self.on_err_args=[]
        self.on_err_kwargs={}
        self.on_out_thread=None
        self.on_err_thread=None

    def execute(self, comm):
        file_number = self.proc.stdin.fileno()
        file = open(file_number, "w+")
        file.write(comm)
        file.close()


    def on_out(function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_out_func=function
        self.on_out_args=args
        self.on_out_kwargs=kwargs

    def on_err(function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_err_func=function
        self.on_err_args=args
        self.on_err_kwargs=kwargs

    def on_out_handle(self):
        for i in iter(self.proc.stdout.readline, ""):
            self.on_out_func(i, *self.on_out_args, **self.on_out_kwargs)

    def start_on_out(self, daemon=False):
        self.on_out_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.on_out_handle)
        self.on_out_thread.setDaemon(daemon)
        self.on_out_thread.start()

    def on_err_handle(self):
        for i in iter(self.proc.stderr.readline, ""):
            self.on_err_func(i, *self.on_err_args, **self.on_err_kwargs)

    def start_on_err(self, daemon=False):
        self.on_err_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.on_err_handle)
        self.on_err_thread.setDaemon(daemon)
        self.on_err_thread.start()

prompt = nodePrompt()
prompt.start_on_out()
prompt.start_on_err()
prompt.execute("console.log(\"HI\");")
time.sleep(1)
prompt.execute("console.log(\"HI\");")
```

Comment: (Also, why are you trying to write to a FD wrapper around the handle at all, instead of just calling `proc.stdin.write(comm)`, and then `proc.stdin.close()`? Note that doing that, you can *still* do only one close; if you don't want to do that, maybe you should stop closing the descriptor at all, and use `proc.stdin.flush()` when you want to force writes to complete without permanently closing the FIFO).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   When I use `proc.stdin.write(comm)` and then `proc.stdin.flush()`, node js still doesn't recieve the input.

Comment: Also, make sure that the string in `comm` contained a newline or other sigil, if the node code is looking for one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   I meant to write `proc.stdin.flush()`. I edited the comment.

Comment: At that point it's more probably that the problem is on the node side. A `write()` and a `flush()`, if there's no exception thrown, really does write.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   I doubt the problem is on the node side. When I closed the stdin, node js recieved the commands as expected and provided the proper output.

Comment: If it does execute after the flush, this sounds like what you've got is a buffering problem (or a node program that's written not to operate on partial input, which comes down to the same thing) -- but the `flush()` on the Python side rules out output buffering, so we need to worry about input buffering on the node side.

Comment: Actually, one quick change -- what happens if you make it `execute('console.log("hi");\n')`, with the `\n` indicating a newline? I wouldn't be surprised at all if node doesn't execute content it receives until it reaches either a newline or the end of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210960/discussion-between-trigangle-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A closed FIFO can't be re-opened. All you can do is not close it until you're really done. Use `flush()` instead to make sure writes happen immediately.

This is a problem with node.js not running code incrementally (or not flushing its output) when its input and output go to pipelines. Python is provably doing the right thing, after fixing your code to work with `self.proc.stdin` directly.

That is, after changing `execute` to be defined as:

```
    def execute(self, comm):
        self.proc.stdin.write(comm)
        self.proc.stdin.flush()
```

...we can monitor the activity of both the Python interpreter and the copy of node.js it starts.

#### Unfortunately, `node` doesn't behave the way you want it to.

Pay attention to the timestamps of the below trace, which used [`sysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) to track operations during your program's execution:

```
5178 18:55:37.047606506 4 python (18260) < write res=19 data=console.log("HI");. 
8239 18:55:37.095849210 1 node (18261) < read res=19 data=console.log("HI");. 
8590 18:55:38.048679102 4 python (18260) < write res=19 data=console.log("HI");. 
8595 18:55:38.048710436 4 python (18260) < close res=0 
8597 18:55:38.048742124 1 node (18261) < read res=19 data=console.log("HI");. 
8603 18:55:38.048911687 1 node (18261) < read res=0 data= 
8633 18:55:38.051116830 1 node (18261) < write res=3 data=HI. 
8634 18:55:38.051158022 6 python (18262) < read res=3 data=HI. 
8636 18:55:38.051199286 6 python (18262) < write res=3 data=HI. 
8642 18:55:38.051400907 1 node (18261) < write res=3 data=HI. 
8643 18:55:38.051441455 6 python (18262) < read res=3 data=HI. 
8645 18:55:38.051459654 6 python (18262) < write res=3 data=HI.
```

Python writes the first `console.log("HI")`, *and Node reads it*, long before Node writes any output at all.

I'd suggest looking into whether Node runs code as it's received when it comes from a non-TTY source, or if it tries to read the entire stream to its end and parse it before running anything.

#### A Suggested Reproducer

If you're going to ask this question for a node audience, consider giving them the following bash script:

```
{
  echo 'console.log("HI");'
  sleep 1
  echo 'console.log("HI");'
  sleep 1
  echo "Already sent both commands to node" >&2
} | node
```

Its output is:

```
Already sent both commands to node
HI
HI
```

...whereas one might hope for at least one HI to be printed earlier, since there's a full two seconds' delay after the first command is sent.

Answer (score -2):

try adding `file.close_proc()` under `file.close()`

Comment: Can you point to the Python standard-library documentation for this? Searching for `site:python.org close_proc` finds no results whatsoever.

Comment: Moreover, because the OP is using `open`, not `os.fdopen`, they're just opening a file *named after* the file descriptor number, not getting an extra handle on the file descriptor for their process's stdin at all. Thus, they wouldn't have access to any methods that are specific to file-like objects that communicate with processes (not that I believe any such methods to exist in the first place).

Comment: @ingenium21   I get following error: `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'close_proc'`.